# Select Top 20 Distinct Rows in Each Category

Tags: sql, hive

I have a database table in the following format.

```
Product   | Date      | Score 

A         | 01/01/18  | 99 

B         | 01/01/18  | 98 

C         | 01/01/18  | 97 

-------------------------- 

A         | 02/01/18  | 99 

B         | 02/01/18  | 98 

C         | 02/01/18  | 97 

-------------------------- 

D         | 03/01/18  | 99 

A         | 03/01/18  | 98 

B         | 03/01/18  | 97 

C         | 03/01/18  | 96
```

I want to pick the first from every month such that there are no repeat products. For example, the output of the above table should be

```
Product   | Date      | Score 

A         | 01/01/18  | 99 

B         | 02/01/18  | 98 

D         | 03/01/18  | 99
```

How do I get this result with a **single sql query**? The actual table is much bigger than this and I want top 20 from every month without repetition.

Comment: This problem is not really suitable for SQL.  It is a hard problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard problem -- a type of subgraph problem that isn't really suitable to SQL.  There is a brute force approach:

```
with jan as (
      select *
      from t
      where date = '2018-01-01'
      limit 1
     ),
     feb as (
      select *
      from t
      where date = '2018-02-01' and
            product not in (select product from jan)
     ),
     mar as (
      select *
      from t
      where date = '2018-03-01' and
            product not in (select product from jan) and
            product not in (select product from feb)
    )
select *
from jan
union all
select *
from feb
union all
select *
from mar;
```

You can generalize this with additional CTEs.  But there is no guarantee that a month will have a product -- even when it could have had one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the number of months is much greater than 3 in the actual database. So, I can't use hard-coded queries.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using row_number.

```
select * from (
select row_Number() over(partition by Product  order by Product ) as rno,* from 
Products   
) as t where t.rno<=20
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want top 20 records every month without repeating products than below solution will be work.

```
select * 
into #temp
from 
(values 
('A','01/01/18','99')
,('B','01/01/18','98') 
,('C','01/01/18','97') 
,('A','02/01/18','99') 
,('B','02/01/18','98') 
,('C','02/01/18','97') 
,('D','03/01/18','99') 
,('A','03/01/18','98') 
,('B','03/01/18','97') 
,('C','03/01/18','96')
) AS VTE (Product ,Date, Score  )

select * from 
(
    select * , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by date,product  order by score ) as rn 
    from #TEMP
)
 A where rn < 20
```